# University of Cambridge: Mistake on the exam? Extending holomorphic functions on intersecting discs

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the following question

> Let $D_1$ and $D_2$ be two overlapping closed discs. Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on some open neighborhood of $D = D_1 \cap D_2$. Show that there exist open neighborhoods $U_j$ of $D_j$ and holomorphic functions $f_j$ on $U_j$ for $j = 1, 2$, such that $f(z) = f_1(z) + f_2(z)$ on $U_1 \cap U_2$.

I am convinced that this is not necessarily true. Here is my counter-example:

Let $D_1$ and $D_2$ be the red and blue circles in the bellow diagram. Morever, let the black one be the unit disc.
[image]
Let
$$
f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{2^n}.
$$
Per [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749560/show-that-fz-sum-n-0-inftyz2n-cant-be-analytically-continued-past), the function does not have an analytic continuation that contains any part of the unit circle. Now, in the question, by the identity theorem, we must have
$$
f_1 = f_2 = \frac{1}{2}f
$$
on $D$. As $f_1$ is holomorphic on $U_1$, it is holomorphic on $D_1$. But this together with the identity theorem on $D_1 \cap D$ gives us that $f$ can be analytically extended through the unit circle, which can not be true.

**Question:** Is my counter example correct?

Comment: I don't understand this assertion. Please could you explain why you think it is true? "by the identity theorem, we must have  $$f_1 = f_2 = \frac{1}{2}f$$ on $D$".

Comment: Hi, I think I made a mistake. I confused myself thinking that $f_1 = f_2$ on $D$. However, I am still confused by the question. My area of concern is how could I split $f$ such that  $f_1$ and $f_2$ are extendable. Surely something weird is going on? This question is taken from this exam https://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/pastpapers/files/2021/paperib_3_2021.pdf It is the last part of question 13.

Comment: Did you study sheaf cohomology?

Comment: Hi @MoisheKohan. No, this is from a second year exam on Complex Analysis (our first complex analysis course)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $U$ be the neigbourhood of $D$ on which $f$ is defined, let $\Delta$ be a neighbourhood of $D$ contained in $U$ and let $C$ be the boundary of $\Delta$. Then, in $\Delta$, $$f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{f(\lambda)}{\lambda-z}d\lambda.$$ Split the boundary into two continuous parts $C_1$ and $C_2$ so that their union is $C$ and $C_1 \cap D_1 = \emptyset$, $C_2 \cap D_2 = \emptyset$ (it is 'obvious' from a picture that you can do this, but you would need to prove it). Then you can use the first result in the question to define $f_1$ as $$f_1(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C_1}\frac{f(\lambda)}{\lambda-z}d\lambda,$$ which will be holomorphic on $D_1$ and $f_2$ as $$f_2(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C_2}\frac{f(\lambda)}{\lambda-z}d\lambda,$$ which will be holomorphic on $D_2$. The sum of $f_1$ and $f_2$ will equal $f$ in $\Delta$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I do not think this is correct. We need $f= f_1+f_2$ on $U_1 \cap U_2$. So we must have it on a neighbourhood of $D$. The issue is now that we have potential singularities on the paths since for example, $C_2$ is properly contained in any neighbourhood of $D$ as note $D$ is closed.

Comment: The answer given above by @mcd needs a little work to make it precise. One needs to shrink the drawn open set to get $C$ and then further shrink it to get a neighbourhood where $f=f_1+f_2$.

Comment: Actually (@Kapil and OP), I misread the question - I though $D$ was a disc. I've amended my suggested solution.

Answer (score 5):

The statement in the question is correct, and your example it not a counterexample.

$f_1$ is defined and holomorphic in a neighborhood $U_1$ of $D_1$, $f_2$ is defined and holomorphic in a neighborhood $U_2$ of $D_2$, and $f_(z) = f_1(z) + f_2(z)$ holds for all $z \in U_1 \cap U_2$. It does *not* follow that $f_1 = f_2$ in $ U_1 \cap U_2$, or that $f$ can be continued analytically beyond any point of its domain.

Here is a simpler example: The function
$$
 f : \Bbb D \to \Bbb C, f(z) = \frac{1}{1-z^2}
$$
is holomorphic in the unit disk and has singular points at $z=-1$ and $z=1$. If we define
$$
 f_1 : B(-1, \sqrt 2) \to \Bbb C, f(z) = \frac{1}{2(1-z)} \, ,\\
 f_2 : B(1, \sqrt 2) \to \Bbb C, f(z) = \frac{1}{2(1+z)} 
$$
then $f_1$ and $f_2$ are holomorphic in the disks $D_1 = B(-1, \sqrt 2)$ and $D_2 = B(1, \sqrt 2)$, respectively.

For $z \in D_1 \cap D_2$ is
$$
 f_1(z) + f_2(z) = \frac{1}{2(1-z)}+\frac{1}{2(1+z)} = \frac{1}{1-z^2} = f(z)
$$
so we have a decomposition as in the given question. But it does not follow that $f_1 = f_2 = \frac{1}{2}f$ in $D_1 \cap D_2$, or that $f$ can be continued analytically beyound its singular points $z=1$ or $z=-1$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I am still confused. The issue is that in your example you have finitely many singularities, and moreover, they are isolated. The issue is that with my example, there are infinitely many and are not.  I am struggling to see how one can decompose it. Bellow, there is an answer, however, as I have commented there too, I think that the argument is faulty but I could be wrong.

Comment: @MathsWizzard: You have $f= f_1+f_2$ on $U_1 \cap U_2$, but you *don't* have $f = f_1 + f_2$ on a neighborhood of $D$. Neither $f_1$ or $f_2$ is even *defined* in a neighborhood of $D$. – I chose a simple example do demonstrate that, but for the general proof (as outlined in the other answer) it does not matter how many singularities $f$ has on the boundary.

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding. The question says that $U_i$ are neighbourhoods of the $D_i$ (discs), so each disci s properly contained in the respective $U_i$, Therefore $D$ it self is properly contained in $U_i$ for each, and hence, in their intersection. Is this not correct?

Comment: @MathsWizzard: $f$ is defined and holomorphic in a neighborhood $U$ of $D = D_1 \cap D_2$. In your example is $U$ the unit disk. $D$ is contained in both $U_i$, but $U$ is not. So you cannot say that $f=f_1 + f_2$ in $U$.